# Task<class> calling a non async method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a 3rd party DLL that I cannot change and I wanted to make asynchronous one of its method.
So I have:

```
procedure bool Food()
{
   Task<ReturnClass> response = SomeDLL.SyncMethod(); // Method returns "ReturnClass"

   response.ContinueWith (_ => 
   {
     return response.Result != null;
   });
 }
```

I get the known compile error:
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'SomeDLL.ReturnClass' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'**

It's important to notice that **I cannot change the 3rd PartyDLL**

1. What's the right way to accomplish this goal?
   I need to wait for the SomeDLL SyncMethod return so that's why I used ContinueWith.
2. Does the procedure bool Foo need to set as "async"?

Comment: You're trying to create a synchronous wrapper for an asynchronous method.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) is a great article about it.  The answer is that in virtually all cases just **don't do this**.  It's generally a sign that something is wrong, and attempting to do this can cause all sorts of problems if you're not very careful.

Comment: @Servy I understand the OP is trying to do the opposite: build an async wrapper for a sync method.

Comment: @ken2k You also shouldn't be doing that, but no, that's not the case.  This method returns a `bool`, not a `Task<bool>`, and `SomeDLL.Method()` clearly returns a `Task`, based on the first line of the method.  This is very much a sync over async wrapper.

Comment: SomeDLL.Method returns "ReturnClass" not a Task.

Comment: @Servy From the question, I understand `SomeDLL.Method()` is sync (_I wanted to make asynchronous one of its method_) and the first line of the method generates a compile-time error the OP is trying to fix.

Comment: @Servy ..Ken2K is right. the method returns a class and I'm trying to wrap that into a Task. Bare in mind I need to wait for the return of the Method()

Comment: Oh, well then that's not a good code sample.  In that case I refer you to [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Comment: Updated sample (sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to make the method async, but you don't say why. If you're looking to gain the scalability improvements of async, then that's not possible: `SyncMethod()` will block a thread and there's nothing you can do about that.

If you're in a UI application and you want gain better responsiveness, then you can do that by invoking your method on a background thread using `Task.Run()`. Something like:

```
async Task<bool> FoodAsync()
{
   Task<ReturnClass> response = Task.Run(() => SomeDLL.SyncMethod());

   return await response != null;
}
```

This assumes you're using C# 5. If that's not the case, you can still do this, but the code is going to be more complicated:

```
Task<bool> FoodAsync()
{
   Task<ReturnClass> response =
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeDLL.SyncMethod());

   return response.ContinueWith(_ => response.Result != null);
}
```

Comment: The DLL is a Twilio DLL that will send a Text message via their APIs. So my thought was that the main thread will get released and another will be used for handling the Twilio API. Isn't that how you achieve further scalability?

Comment: @EagertoLearn If you're talking about ASP.NET application (or something like that), then no, that won't help you at all. In ASP.NET, there is no “main thread” and you get better scalability by using smaller number of threads. So just switching from one thread to another is useless.